# Using the Frobenius method, how to solve $xy''+y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

$$xy''+y=0$$

Example-4 from section 6.2 of Differential Equations with Boundary-Value Problems book.
Here's the solution I'm stuck in the middle of:

[image: Solution]

Comment: You should have $+c_k$ in the summand, not $-c_k$. The indicial equation tells you either $r=0$ or $r=1$; either one should give you the same solution. A second solution should be [obtainable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method#%22The_exceptional_cases%22:_roots_separated_by_an_integer) from there.